# Xquery - how do I apply a map to a sequence?

Tags: dictionary, xquery

I would like to apply a function to each element in a sequence and get the result. Can someone point me in the right direction?

e.g.

```
declare function local:ToTextNode($string as xs:string) as Node()
{
text { $string }
};
```

I want to apply the above to:

```
('foo','bar','baz')
```

...and get a sequence of nodes.

Comment: There were some syntax errors in your function: it is `Node()`, not `xs:node` and you cannot use `return` without any `let` or `for`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [simple map operator `!`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-map-operator), but it requires an XQuery processor implementing XQuery 3.0.

```
declare function local:ToTextNode($string as xs:string) as node()
{
  text { $string }
};

('foo','bar','baz') ! local:ToTextNode(.)
```

You do not need to define a function for that, you can also directly use the text node constructor:

```
('foo','bar','baz') ! text { . }
```

If your XQuery engine does not support the map operator (yet), you will have to use a flwor expression:

```
for $i in ('foo','bar','baz')
return text { $i }
```